# avoid eval when calling functions which are overloaded for different eigen matrix types

Tags: c++, overloading, eigen, lazy-evaluation, eigen3

I often find myself overloading functions for different eigen matrix types.
Depending on how i call them, there's the need to explicitly call eval() on the parameters to hint at the right overload, f.e. when all are lazy evaluated CwiseBinaryOps:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
void ef(Eigen::Vector2d const& v) {}
void ef(Eigen::Vector3d const& v) {}
int main() {
    ef(Eigen::Vector3d() + Eigen::Vector3d()); // ambiguous call to overloaded function
    ef((Eigen::Vector3d() + Eigen::Vector3d()).eval());
}
```

Here's a [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/h7MzE6).

Are there ways to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

The type of `Eigen::Vector3d() + Eigen::Vector3d()` is an expression template. It doesn't evaluate to `Eigen::Vector3d` until `eval()` is called.

If you don't want to explicitly call `eval()`, the `ef` function needs to take expression template as argument, e.g.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

template <typename Derived>
void ef(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> const& v) {}

int main()
{
    ef(Eigen::Vector2d() + Eigen::Vector2d());
    ef(Eigen::Vector3d() + Eigen::Vector3d());
}
```

You can check the size of v in `ef` to do different things for `Vector2d` and `Vector3d`.